# How to save more than one line in SD card memory

Tags: esp32

I am trying to store certain text in SC Card memory, but the SD Card save the last line or it does not work at all
I'm working with ESP32 microcontroller
this is my code

```cpp
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <SD.h>

    File myFile;
    int i=0;
    void setup() {
        // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
        Serial.begin(9600);
        while (!Serial) {
             ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
        }


        Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

        if (!SD.begin(5)) {
           Serial.println("initialization failed!");
           while (1);
       }
       Serial.println("initialization done.");

    }

   void loop() {
      // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
      // so you have to close this one before opening another.
     myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

     // if the file opened okay, write to it:
     if (myFile) {
       Serial.print("Writing to test.txt...");
       myFile.println("testing"+i);
       // close the file:
       myFile.close();
       Serial.println("done.");
     } else {
         // if the file didn't open, print an error:
         Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
       }
     
      i++;

    }
```

it must print

```
{testing 0
 testing 1
 testing 2
.....
 testing n
}
```

where n={0-infinity}
but it just saves the last line which {testing n } the last line

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `last line`? ... it is unclear what is the problem ... please provide a clear description of what happens

Comment: I'm new here :), what about now it's clear enough?

Comment: google `esp32 sd file append`

Comment: Really weird, I would have done the same thing you did... Did you try to switch sd card? Or at least format? May be try starting over with https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Datalogger , which seems to append to file some string.

Comment: I tried all of that , switch the Sd card , the Sd module , and the adapter

Answer (score 2):

Change `FILE_WRITE` to `FILE_APPEND`.

I.e `myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);` becomes `myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_APPEND);`.

As it is, your `loop()` function is called repeatedly, and each time it creates a new file called "test.txt", overwriting the previous one.

Comment: @saja did that solve your problem?